# How HandlerFunc(f) convert a function to an interface type?

Tags: go

When check following code, got a doubt with type convert from function to interface.

---

### Code

**http_hello.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// hello http,
func helloHttp() {
    // register handler,
    http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(helloHandler))

    // start server,
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }

}

// handler function - hello,
func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, you've requested: %s\n", r.URL.Path)
}

func main() {
    helloHttp()
}
```

The above code works.

*(Then I tried to write a small program to check is this a general feature, but it won't work, check following code)*

**func_to_intf.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// an interface,
type Adder interface {
    add(a, b int) int
}

// alias of a function signature,
type AdderFunc func(int, int) int

// a simple add function,
func simpleAdd(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

// call Adder interface to perform add,
func doAdd(a, b int, f Adder) int {
    return f.add(a, b)
}

func funcToIntf() {
    fa := AdderFunc(simpleAdd)
    fmt.Printf("%#v, type: %T\n", fa, fa)

    a, b := 1, 2
    sum := doAdd(a, b, fa)
    fmt.Printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, sum)
}

func main() {
    funcToIntf()
}
```

**Output:**

> ./func_to_intf.go:30:14: cannot use fa (type AdderFunc) as type Adder
>   in argument to doAdd:     AdderFunc does not implement Adder (missing add
>   method)

---

### Questions

1. `http.HandlerFunc(helloHandler)` get a value of type `http.Handler`, since that's what `http.Handle()` expect, is that correct?
2. If yes, then means it convert a function into a value of an interface type, how did that happen?

   - Is this a built-in feature of go?
     I did a test (as in `func_to_intf.go` above), and seems not.
   - Or, is `http.HandlerFunc`'s special implementation achieve that?

---

### @Update - Summary

*(Though the answer(s) addressed the questions pretty well, but after reviewing & more testing, there are several other go features required to totally erase the original doubt, as following.)*

- Function type.
  Function is value, and it has type.
  Function type could be defined via `type` keyword on a function signature.
  e.g `type AdderFunc func(int, int) int`
- Type convertor `Ｔ(v)` on function.
  Any function could be converted to a function type with the same signature, just via `T(v)`, use function type name as `T`, and actual function as `v`.
  Then when the new value is called, the actual function `v` is called.
  e.g `fa := AdderFunc(simpleAdd)`
  *(this is blur to me before asking the question, and that's one of the main reason I was confused)*.

Comment: `http.HandlerFunc(helloHandler)` returns a value of type `http.HandlerFunc`. That type happens to implement `http.Handler`, so you can pass it to `http.Handle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a simple type-conversion.

In Go you can define custom type besides `struct`s. In this case, `http.HandlerFunc` is a function type, `func(http.ResponseWriter,*http.Request)`. Since your function is of the same underlying type (signature) as the custom type, it can be converted to it.

Furthermore, code can define methods on custom type, no matter what underlying type it is, or whether it is a `struct` or not. In this case, `http` package defines `ServeHTTP` method on it, and of course, it just calls the function itself.

You can read the source code here: https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=58384:58444#L1936

As for the adder in your sample code, you can do the same: Define a method on `AdderFunc`.

```
func (a AdderFunc) add(x, y int) int {
    return a(x, y)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5mf_afHLQA2

Comment: A function could be converted into function type via `T(v)` is not clear to me originally, that's the major reason caused my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

`http.HandlerFunc` is a type that satisfy interface `http.Handler` by providing method `http.ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)`.

`http.HandlerFunc(helloHandler)` is a type conversion which convert types with same underlying base type but different method set.

You example [working](https://play.golang.org/p/kmLBTUIBsqN)

Answer (score 1):

Not special or built-in feature. Instead `http.HandlerFunc` is a type that implements the `http.Handler` interface. Have a look at its implementation which is quite nifty https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d3c3aaa61f7598f275f30fabd3749379fe0f2720/src/net/http/server.go#L1956

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) say:

> The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a Handler that calls f.

So, it's not a function, but a wrapper type, declared as:

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

But Go allows (and that's one of its greatest features, in my opinion) to make any newly declared type implement any possible interface just by defining the require method. So the type `HandlerFunc` implements the interface `Handler` by defining the method [`ServeHttp`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc). The implementation just calls the wrapped function.